# cx_Oracle 6.0rc1 - Oracle client library cannot be loaded %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have a Python script as follows:

```
print ("Python version: " + platform.python_version())
print ("cx_Oracle version: " + cx_Oracle.version)
print ("Oracle client: " + str(cx_Oracle.clientversion()).replace(', ','.'))

OraUid="secret"                 
OraPwd="secret"              
OraDB="secret"               

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(OraUid + "/" + OraPwd + "@" + OraDB)
```

I use the Windows terminal to run this, and I get the following error.
[image]

I also have a 64 bits windows 7 | Python 2.7 32 bit | Oracle Client 32 and 64 Bit versions on my system. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python, cx_Oracle and Oracle client installation must all be 64-bit or all 32-bit. You cannot mix and match. The error you are getting suggests that you are trying to load a 64-bit Oracle client with a 32-bit Python. Make sure that if you are using 32-bit Python that the 32-bit Oracle client libraries are in your PATH environment variable first.

Comment: that makes sense
so my python, oracle client, and the cx_oracle have to all be the same bit version?
This fixed it btw.
It was strange that 5.2.1 version of cx_Oracle worked, but the 6.x version did not, but I assume whatever version of cx_oracle I have it should match bit by bit to my Oracle client.

Comment: Yes, it all has to match. :-) And if this resolved your question, please accept the answer! Thanks.

Comment: Anthony: so another follow up to your comment would be, if I have a 64 bit Oracle client, and I have a 3.6 version of Python; when I do the pip install cx_Oracle -- pre under my "scripts folder", will that automagically grab the correct bit version of cx_Oracle, along with the correct version that matches my Python version.

Comment: If you use the command "python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade --pre" to install cx_Oracle, it will automatically determine your platform, architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) and download and install the correct binary. Much simpler and less prone to error! Of course, you still have to make sure your Oracle Instant Client matches!